# Casting data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape, transpose, tidyr

My data look like the following:

```
dput(head(dat, 10)
structure(list(Label = c("Nuclear Blast", "Nuclear Blast", "Nuclear Blast", 
                     "Nuclear Blast", "Nuclear Blast", "Nuclear Blast", "Nuclear Blast", 
                     "Metal Blade Records", "Metal Blade Records", "Metal Blade Records"
), Info = c("Germany", " +49 7162 9280-0 ", "active", " N/A ", 
        "1987", "\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tAnstalt Records,\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tArctic Serenades,\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tCannibalised Serial Killer,\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tDeathwish Office,\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tEpica,\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tGore Records,\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tGrind Syndicate Media,\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tNuclear Blast America,\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tNuclear Blast Brasil,\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tNuclear Blast Entertainment,\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tRadiation Records,\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tRevolution Entertainment\t\t\t\t\t      ", 
        "Yes", " 5737 Kanan Road #143\n\nAgoura Hills, California 91301 ", 
        "United States", " N/A ")), .Names = c("Label", "Info"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                               10L), class = "data.frame")
```

How do I reshape it so it looks like the following?

```
  Label                 Var1            Var2            Var3      Var4   Var5    Var6                Var7
1 Nuclear Blast        Germany      +49 7162 9280-0     active    N/A    1987    Anstalt Records...  Yes 
2 Metal Blade Records  5737 Kanan.. United States       N/A
```

I realize the number of rows for each label is inconsistent but I can clean that up later in excel or R.

Comment: why the 8th row `none` did appear at 4th col-3rd row of transformed data?

Comment: Can't see a pattern. Please change the expected output to match your example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)

dat[, Col:= paste0('Var', 1:.N), by='Label']

dat = dcast.data.table(dat, Label ~ Col, value.var='Info')
```

Comment: Works with the sample data provided but not with the original data. I've provided a reproducible example with `dput` in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `dplyr/tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat %>% 
    group_by(Label) %>% #group by Label
    mutate(Col = paste0("Var", row_number())) %>% #create a sequence column
    spread(Col, Info) #spread to wide format
```